# Calculated field for difference between two times

Tags: calculated-column, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I have a list with a "Start" field and "End" field. I'm using a calculated field to determine the difference in hours and minutes between the two.
Start - 9:00 am
End - 10:30 am
=TEXT(End-Start,"h:mm")

The problem I have is that I don't want the time result to display as 2:30... but I can't figure out how to have the time display as 2.5 so that I can use that field to calculate the pay.

I tried using =INT but then it doesn't return the 30 minutes.

Is there another way to return the information in the format I want?

Answer (score 4):

When you subtract a date field from another date field in a calculated column, the result is given in days.

You can therefore multiply the difference by 24 to get the result in hours, so your formula would likely look like this: `=24*(End-Start)`

Make sure to set your calculated column to return a number instead of text.

Comment: Damn, beat me by the second. :)

Comment: @Christoffer Great minds answer alike!

Answer (score 3):

Change your calculation to

```
=24*(start-end)
```

and set the column type to `Number` with 1 decimal.